# Searchbar textdidchange delegate function not getting called for languages like japanese and chinese

Tags: ios

I'am working on a multilingual application.The application contains a tableview with search bar when using languages like japanese and chinese on entering a letter in the keyboard the delegate function textdidchange never gets called ,for other languages like english ,german etc its working fine

So my question is

Are we supposed to do something different for the japanese and chinese keyboard ?
Answers are very much appreciate.

thank you in advance

Comment: 1. Past your `textDidChange` code here please. 2. Japanese and chinese keyboards are slightly different from English because you need to select a character by multiple touches to keyboard.

Comment: thank u Maxim you are right a character is defined by multiple touches